# How to remove null values in list of objects using Circe

Tags: scala, circe

I'm trying to encode a list of objects using Circe, something that looks similar to:

`val test = Seq(MyObject("hello", None, 1, 2, None)`

I'm trying to parse this using Circe:

`test.asJson`

But this creates the JSON object:

```
[
  {
    name: "hello",
    someVal: null,
    someNum: 1,
    anotherNum: 2,
    anotherVal: null
  }
]
```

I've tried running `asJson` with `.dropNullValues`, but that doesn't seem to access the null values inside of the object.  Is there a way to drop the null values inside of the objects?

I'm expecting something more like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "hello",
    someNum: 1,
    anotherNum: 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Please consider to change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Circe provides the function `deepDropNullValues` in the `Json` class.

Example: `test.asJson.deepDropNullValues`

Comment: That is the simplest answer.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: I needed to upgrade to Circe version "0.14.1" to get `deepDropNullValues`, but after that it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Is there some global configuration for this? It's a bit cumbersome to do it explicitly for every object.

Answer (score 4):

The answer that was suggested by [@iva-kmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11310016/iva-kam) is good, but it can be done better!

This mechanic is already [implemented in circe](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/e6e924e6256359001c94f77656a315d9cdbb6d77/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Json.scala#L177), just call it:

```scala
implicit val fooEnc: Encoder[Foo] = deriveEncoder[Foo].mapJson(_.dropNullValues) // or _.deepDropNullValues
```

Answer (score 3):

You see `field: null` because circe turns `Option[T]` to `t.asJson` on `Some[T]` and `JsonNull` on `None`, and default case class encoder just puts all fields to the `JsonObject`. In a way that circe uses to encode sealed trait family, it may use these `null` fields to distinguish classes like

```
sealed trait Foo
case class Bar(a: Option[String])
case class Baz(a: Option[String], b: Option[String])
```

So, if you *really* want to drop this information and need one-way conversion with information loss, you can map resulting `Json` to drop all and every null field with code like that:

```
implicit val fooEnc: Encoder[Foo] = deriveEncoder[Foo].mapJsonObject{jsonObj => jsonObj.filter{case (k,v) => !v.isNull}}
```

However, you should write such a custom codec for any class you want to drop null fields. To post-process your json, you can use fold on resulting json:

```
  val json: Json = ???
  json.fold[Json](
    Json.Null,
    Json.fromBoolean,
    {_.asJson},
    {_.asJson},
    {_.asJson},
    {jsonObj => jsonObj.filter{case (k,v) => !v.isNull}.asJson}
  )
```

or implement a custom folder.